# I used kill -9 -1 and now ubuntu gui won't load on boot

Tags: 18.10, kill

I am still fairly new to linux and ubuntu and I decided it would be a good idea to run "kill -9 -1" to fix an error I was having because I saw it on some forum. Naturally that killed all the processes so I rebooted and now I can't get any drivers or the gui to load. It just boots into the cli with no drivers loaded.

Comment: When it boots to CLI, what prompt do you get and what message is on the screen?

Note: I suspect the issue may be separate to your running `kill -9 -1` which shouldn't normally do anything a reboot won't fix, even though it's overkill (literally).

Comment: I ran sudo apt autoremove beforehand but that's about it. The GUI closed when i ran kill -9 -1. When I boot now i get the login screen - the minimal ubuntu interface

Comment: The autoremove wouldn't in itself do anything but suggests you ran another command to remove some packages before it.  What were you doing at the time you ran the autoremove?

Comment: i installed python 3.7 and removed python 3.6. Then I noticed that ctrl-alt-t was not opening a new terminal so I looked it up and somebody said that they used the kill command when that happens. i used sudo apt remove python3, sudo apt autoremove, and sudo apt clean beforehand.

Comment: Messing around with python is an excellent way to destroy your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Python or the python installation? Because I wasn't doing anything in python

Comment: The python installation.